# Clear input value for react-pin-input upon clicking on submit button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on an OTP page, and was trying if there is a way to clear input value for react-pin-input after user clicks on the submit OTP button.

```
<PinInput
  ref={pintInputRef}
  length={6}
  secret
  type="numeric"
  inputMode="numeric"
  onComplete={(value) => {
    handleOnCompleteInput(value);
  }}
  autoSelect={true}
  regexCriteria={/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/}
/>

<Button
  type="primary"
  size="large"
  block
  htmlType="submit"
  onClick={handleSubmit}
> Verify </Button>

const handleSubmit = () => {
  // SET PIN INPUT TO EMPTY
}
```

I have tried useRef and set ref.current.value = ""  but it does not work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-shirley-dyqk65?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your input is on a different page, I think you have to use props to achieve this, can you make a codesand box ?

Comment: Hey, useRef not work for ref.current.value = "" for this anymore.

Comment: @Ankit updated with the codesanbox link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useRef` hook and `ref` prop of `PinInput` component:

1. Define a variable:

   ```
   let ele = useRef();
   ```
2. Add `ele.clear()` on `handleSubmit`:

   ```
   const handleSubmit = () => {
     ele.clear();
   };
   ```
3. Add `ref` to `PinInput`:

   ```
   <PinInput
       length={6}
       secret
       type="numeric"
       inputMode="numeric"
       onComplete={(value) => {
         handleOnCompleteInput(value);
       }}
       autoSelect={true}
       regexCriteria={/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/}
       ref={(n) => (ele = n)} /*Set ref */
     />
   ```

[image: Edit great-currying-qgx1l6]

Comment: I changed `let ele = useRef(); ` to `let pinInputRef: PinInput | null;`, it works! Thanks

Comment: I changed `ele.clear();` to `ele.clear`. Works for me!